# <img> sizes attribute supported in Safari but missing from JS img object

Tags: javascript, safari, responsive-images

Safari now supports `<img> srcset & sizes` attributes (http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) and in testing it works.

If you visit the feature detection library http://featurejs.com using Safari it (wrongly) reports that `sizes` is *not* supported.

Because `sizes` is missing from the img object.

If I visit a page in Safari which has an image defined something like:

```
<img srcset="smallpic.jpg 300w, mediumpic.jpg 600w, bigpic.jpg 1000w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw,
            50vw" >
```

then in the console try this:

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');

console.log(img.srcset); // prints srcset definition
console.log(img.sizes);  // undefined
```

But it correctly reports `img.sizes` in Chrome or Firefox.

I want to be able to manipulate sizes for dynamically added content.

Does anyone know any way to access the property? Maybe in Safari it goes by another name (wishful thinking).

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in Safari, but you can work around it by just retrieving the attribute value directly with `img.getAttribute("sizes");`

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I already tried retrieving the attribute like that, which works, and you can also notionally set the attribute with img.setAttribute(). Unfortunately it has no effect, the sizes property is missing on the img element node and I've concluded it is a dead end trying to get it to work in Safari.